# Getting affected row count when there is no resultset object

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

I have given a pl/sql procedure that I am supposed to call from java code through jdbc.

```
public boolean deleteCompany(TimeStamp timestamp, Long companyId){
String str = "{call Delete_Company(?,?)}";
        CallableStatement statement =  null; 
        boolean deleted = false;
        try{
            statement = conn.prepareCall(str);
            statement.setLong(1,companyId);
            statement.setTimestamp(2,timeStamp);
            statement.execute();
            deleted = true;
            return deleted;
        }finally{
            statement.close();
        }  
}
```

The problem is even if I send the wrong id number it obviously executes statement so varaible deleted becomes true. I tried .executeUpdate() method to be able to get affected row counts but it did not work properly cause when in both cases(when deletion/no deletion happened) it retrieved 1. I suppose the problem is the pl/sql procedure I am using just performs delete operation but not retrieve any result set object. So neither executeUpdate() nor getUpdateCount() methods does not help me. My question is there any way I can get affected  row counts even if I have no result set object?

FYI: I understand that affected row count could be sent as a out parameter from pl/sql procedure, but I have no authority to make any change on the db side.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change the stored procedure, one solution is to do the following

1. Get the number of rows before calling an update operation (`select count(*) from your_tbl where .....)`
2. Delete the records as you're already doing
3. Get the number of rows after the delete action and check if the number of affected rows is the same as in #1 (num_rows#1 - num_rows#3)

Other transactions can still make this approach somewhat unreliable because they can also change your table between steps #1 and #3.
If that's a concern for you, then you should use transactions (just place your Java code in a transaction).

Comment: thanks for the answer , but I am aware of the solution you mentioned. As I stated in my post, I need a hack without interfering with a signature of the called stored procedure @dsp_user.

Comment: I've updated my answer (sorry didn't see the last part)

Answer (score -2):

Your `statement.execute();` returns a boolean value and it always return true if the execution is success irrespective of what the procedure is doing on call. Further you can refer the below code for what you are looking.

```
...

    boolean hadResults = cStmt.execute();

    //
    // Process all returned result sets
    //

    while (hadResults) {
        ResultSet rs = cStmt.getResultSet();

        // process result set
        ...

        hadResults = cStmt.getMoreResults();
    }

    //
    // Retrieve output parameters
    //
    // Connector/J supports both index-based and
    // name-based retrieval
    //

    int outputValue = cStmt.getInt(2); // index-based

    outputValue = cStmt.getInt("inOutParam"); // name-based

...
```

Comment: `Prepared/CallableStatement.execute()` returns `true` if the first result is a result set and `false` if it is an update count, it does not always return true if it is a success; failure would always result in an exception.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my answer specifically meant to the OP where he's trying to call a procedure, in which case it always returns `true` when call is successful.

Comment: Maybe for Oracle, but not for JDBC in general.